Closed - MAUI - Error in Vs2022 creating package for distribution
I'm creating a MAUI project in VS 2022. All work fine, also in emulator. So, I wanna create a APK for testing in real smartphones.. I set "release" and from "Compilation" -> Create package for "new project".. Works a bit of time and raises an error with no number:

"L'ID di pacchetto 'New Project' contiene caratteri non validi. Esempi di ID di pacchetto validi sono 'MyPackage' e 'MyPackage.Sample'. "C:\Program Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.200\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\buildCrossTargeting\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets   221"

Translating means something like

"Package Id 'New Project' contains invalid characters. Valid package IDs are 'MyPackage' and 'MyPackage.Sample'"

But the file referred isn't contained in my project..
Environment :
Win 11
VS 2022
Net 8.0
Cannot find any solution online or documentation.
Set output for Android to APK with no changes (in project properties)

You can refer to this answer: How do I create a ".apk" bundle in .NET Maui android app, generate apk via command line.

@JianweiSun-MSFT nothing to do, error written above block creation of package and procedures written cannot be completed.
My problem is the error, the way I try to use is correct.

Restarted PC & Visual Studio and now works.. i don't know why...

Well, according to your comment, as a wiki answer.
About the error:

"L'ID di pacchetto 'New Project' contiene caratteri non validi. Esempi
di ID di pacchetto validi sono 'MyPackage' e 'MyPackage.Sample'.
"C:\Program
Files\dotnet\sdk\8.0.200\Sdks\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack\buildCrossTargeting\NuGet.Build.Tasks.Pack.targets
221"

or this:

"Package Id 'New Project' contains invalid characters. Valid package
IDs are 'MyPackage' and 'MyPackage.Sample'"

Restarting PC & Visual Studio can fixing it. You say don't know why. It should be related to restarting VS, which will automatically restore package.
And this step fix the error above.
